# PHP using define for images

Tags: php

does php allow the use of the define function for images

```
define("IF", '<img src="image.jpg" width="50" height="50" />');
```

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't define an image, it defines a string that is an HTML tag for an image. Can PHP define constants as string values? Yes.

Comment: @hgbso Also, IF is a reserved word. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php